python mysql.connector does not throw any error or message, only exit from application
I am trying to connect my localhost mysql server. My personel computer succusfully connect to mysql server with tis python code:
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

class DatabaseHelper():
    def __init__(self): 
        self.host = "localhost"
        self.user = "root"
        self.password = "mysql"
        self.database = "temperedglassdb"
        self.db = None
        
    def connectDb(self):
        try:
            print("Started")
            if not self.isConnected():
                self.db = mysql.connector.connect(
                            host = self.host, 
                            user = self.user, 
                            password = self.password, 
                            database = self.database)
            print("Finished")
            print(self.db)
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        
    def isConnected(self):
        if self.db is not None:
            return self.db.is_connected()
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    db = DatabaseHelper()
    db.connectDb()

Prints ->
Started

But on my work computer which has many organizational restriction. I could not connect to localhost mysql server on it. And this code does not throws any warning or error or any message to resolve the issue?

How do i learn which problems is occours?

So what you're saying is that the code (as posted), prints nothing?

Yes @ewokx, prints nothing

I'd suggest you add a bit more print statements to the code to determine where it goes.  How are you running this code?

How do you know you this code did not connect to the mysql server? You do not any checks or try to interact with the database in any way in the code.

I wroted print("Started") before the connection and wrote print("Fisinhed") after the connection. Started printed but Finished did not printed. @ewokx

Because it is exiting before anything printed @Shadow. Also I tried to get any data from database

Remove the try/except and the system will break with the error

I tried but also did not print anything @nacho

It is running on visual studio with python interpreter in windows environment @ewokx

Actually this happened because of visual studio based error. I tried on different computer and it is working correctly. I assume the visual stuido did not installed properly. After I checked Event Viewer, I saw an MSVCP140.dll error.
Also I reinstalled vc_redist.x64.exe. It solved for me!

If your organization's computer is connected to a domain, it may be assigned a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). In this case, "localhost" may not work as expected.
Check with hostname command and verify.

But we installed server on localhost (on organization computer)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
